# How to bind the files and Model posted from FormData in Asp.Net WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have to post the multiple files including the Model from the client to server. File is posted using form data.

On Server I wanted my field and value to be bind as:

```
public class Information
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFile file { get; set; }
}
public class ModelPost
{
    public List<Information> selectedFile { get; set; }
}
```

In server i tried by this ways:

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);
var result = await httpRequestMessage.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
var deserializedName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ModelPost>(result.FormData["model"]);
```

But this produces an error

`Could not create an instance of type System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase.`

Why i am not being to bind the files send through form data directly to `HttpPostedFileBase`?

I am posting my files from the `vue.js`.

Is there any extension to bind the file directly during `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`?